# MySql sum records daily from 2:00 am instead of midnight.

Tags: mysql, date

For a business closing at 2:00 am, daily accounting ends then. How do I write or simplify this query to sum daily traffic where the top of the clock is actually at 2:00.

```
    SELECT date( CAST( Time - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AS DATETIME ) ) AS date, 
CAST( (sum( `in_count` ) + sum( `out_count` ) ) /2 AS UNSIGNED) AS count
FROM establishment
LEFT JOIN `device` ON establishment.establishment_ID = device.establishment_ID
LEFT JOIN `device_state` ON device.device_id = device_state.device_ID
WHERE establishment.establishment_ID =1
AND date(CAST( Time - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AS DATETIME ))
BETWEEN '2013-02-01' AND '2013-03-01'
GROUP BY dayofmonth( CAST( Time - INTERVAL 2 HOUR AS DATETIME ))
ORDER BY Time
```

Comment: You are using correct approach of deducting 2 hours from your date so all counts within 2 am will be part of previous day. What problem you are facing ?

Comment: _“You are using correct approach of deducting 2 hours from your date”_ – I don’t think so, because it will most likely lead to problems with daylight saving time changes …

Comment: I was wondering if there is a better way to write the query or if there's a function to do that in MySQL or in PHP.
Like CBroe suggested, DST is the issue I am having a hard time handling as well!